# Make an android app in multiple languages

Tags: android

I want to use drop-down list in my app to change my app language. How can I do that? I don't want to change OS language.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only want to provide localization to your application only, not to the system level.

**Step 1:**
Create different values files inside `res` folder, e.g. values.xml, values-ar.xml, etc.

**Step 2:**
As you said, provide a language selection option, based on the language option selected by user, change the preference settings:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Above code would change the locale of the application and it would select particular values file based on the locale selected by user.

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```